# Stable Linux kernel version with RTPreempt Patch for Raspberry Pi3 ModelB

Tags: pi-3, kernel, real-time

I am installing a real time preempt kernel for my Raspberry Pi3 ModelB.

I installed the linux kernel version 4.4.50 and I patched this kernel with RT_Preempt patch-4.4.50-rt63. However, every time I want to check my system latency (using cyclictest) , my OS completely freezes.

I would like to know if this happens because of the version of the kernel that I am using, and/or the rt_patch. If so, does anyone know a stable RT_kernel for a Raspberry Pi ModelB?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It is not about the kernel or the rt_patch, but there is a bug in the FIQ USB implementation, which is only made more evident by the usage of the RT patch.

This forum was very helplful to solve my system freezing problem : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=159170